# Template for Evolutionary Intelligence Springer journal

Tags: formatting, templates

I am a bit new to latex, is there anyone can help to find latex template for Evolutionary Intelligence, a journal from Springer?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ask your editor or use the regular springer journal. Also have a look at the author guidelines.

Comment: for any journal there is no point in faking the layout in latex. Either the journal accepts latex input in which case _they_ will supply an official template, or they do not, in which case just use `article class, as the journal will re-key the article anyway so no part of the latex styling will be used.

Answer (score 4):

the journal author submission guidelines

https://www.springer.com/engineering/computational+intelligence+and+complexity/journal/12065?detailsPage=pltci_1060534

Link to a zip file for the latex macros to be used for LaTeX manuscripts

http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198_220518.zip